while upgrading camel dependency getting errors for below codes | Failed to create route | failed to resolve endpoint | no bean found |
Not able to run the application successfully due to below code snippet.
**in application-local.yml file
**
com.info.aqbypass:
select:
 query: sql:SELECT * FROM EEM_EVENT WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'POLICYDOC' AND STATUS= 0?dataSource=dataSource

pllongTimer: timer://pollingTimer?period=5s
**in java class
**
@service

public class PolicyDocDeliverAdaperRouter extends RouteBuilder {

@Value("${com.info.aqbypass.select.query}")

private String selectQuery;

@Value("${com.info.aqbypass.pollingTimer}")

private String pollingTimer;

@Autowired

private PolicyDocDeliverProcessor policyDocDeliverProcessor;

@Converter

@Override

public void configure() { 

from(pollingTimer).to(selectQuery)

 .log(loggingLevel.INFO, message: "Processing for ::${body}")

 .process(policyDocDeliverProcessor);

}}

Application is failing after run.
below dependency is being used
camel-sql, camel-core, camel-dataset, camel-test-spring, camel-jms-starter, camel-core-starter.
